# Tracking two different user types with Google Analytics?

Tags: statistics, google-analytics

We've got a site with two types of users:

- Guests
- Registered users

What we are looking for is a method to track both types of users within just one Google Analytics profile. We believe a registered user stays more in the site and has a higher page view count that a guest.

Could this be possible within just one profile?
Could there be a way to show custom reports in the profile page to show both user's average time and guests average time?

I know Analytics is such a powerful application, but I'm no guru and I couldn't find anything on Google.

Thanks.

**Bounty Update**

I know it has to do with filters. In your answer please share code and step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use custom variables in GA to track different types of users. Take a look at this example in the GA docs for more information. http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#examples

This is how I would do it:

- When the user session starts, if the user is not a registered user, set a custom variable like so:

```
   pageTracker._setCustomVar(
      1,             // This custom var is set to slot #1
      "User Type",   // The name of the custom varaible
      "Guest",      // Sets the value of "User Type" to "Guest" for non registered users
       2             // Sets the scope to session-level  
   );
   pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

- After the user logs in, use the following code.

```
   pageTracker._setCustomVar(
      1,             
      "User Type",   
      "Registered User",
       2              
   );
   pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

Now you should be able to see `User Type` as a custom variable in your reports.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are using the asynchronous tracking script (http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html) then you have to use:
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, "User Type", "Guest", 2]);
and
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, "User Type", "Registered User", 2]);
before the call to _trackPageview, that in the asynchronous way is:
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

Comment: @electroportal +1 for async :)

Answer (score 2):

what you will need to do is amend the google script at the bottom of your page when it loads to show the state of this custom value.

take a look at for more info. 
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html

what i think you atually want to do is more custom visitor segmentation. 
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingVisitorSegments.html