# Google Analytics tracking user types issue

Tags: javascript, django, google-analytics

My task is to track registered and guest users on my site.

I use GA code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250132/tracking-two-different-user-types-with-google-analytics).

Problem, that in Custom Variables report i see incorrect information. For example, I have 700 unique visitors, but only 60 of them with "user type".

Here is the screenshoot:
[image]

As I understand there should be 688 visits and 688 "User Type" visits. What's wrong?

Here is my Djano code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{{ GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY }}']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.site.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,
      'User Type',
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}'Registered User'{% else %}'Guest'{% endif %},
      2
   ]);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: btw I hadn't seen that `_trackPageLoadTime` before so I investigated it and it seems that since 11 nov you dont need to manually add this in any more, it is [automatically tracked](http://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1205784&topic=1120718)

Comment: Thank you for this information, but I don't thinks that this is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `_setCustomVar` **before** your `_trackPageview`. Otherwise, the custom variable data doesn't bind (ie, gets sent in the `__utm.gif` hit and stored in cookies), and custom variable isn't tracked.

The 10% of visits that are showing custom variables are likely from pages on which there were other hits (events, ecommerce, etc.) that *did* carry the custom variable data. If you move the `_setCustomVar` to be before `_trackPageview` (but after `_setDomainName`), it should track 100%.

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{{ GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY }}']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.site.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,
      'User Type',
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}'Registered User'{% else %}'Guest'{% endif %},
      2
   ]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);
```

Comment: Wow, great! i'll change this today and i'll approve you answer as soon as i'll get data from GA.

Comment: Thank you very much and hapy New Year! =)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the custom var is being set on all pages that use that _setAccount value?

Could it have been missed in some section which would be putting it off?

Are you breaching any of these limits for session level custom variables?

> For any web property, you can create as many distinct session-level
>   custom variables as can be defined with a 64-byte key-value pair
>   limit.
>
> For any given user session, you can set up to 5 session-level
>   variables.

Comment: GA code is the same in all pages. I don't think that I has breaching any limits.